# Teleporting css navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar

so I am working with css, which I suck with, and I got my code to work the way I want so I am not looking for snarky comments saying my coding sucks :P

Anyways I used a gif just to show what it is doing - I will also provide the code underneath.

https://gyazo.com/3756eb0c3b6246d8b8f74cad6614839a

The links sort of teleport when clicked IE click the one is last position and none move, click one in say first all move left by one 'link space' I don't really know how to explain this, so excuse any slip ups I have haha. Anyways here is the code, Instead of using a styles.css file I just use the style section of my index.html - I am going to post all my style area just in case it may be conflicting, I will seperate where it ends the navbar however just to make it simpler for viewing.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #757575;
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

It seems I can't past the other section of code here so I am going to pastebin it instead:

Pastebin of code after navbar: [pastebin/w1J1Yixu](http://pastebin.com/w1J1Yixu)

Pastebin of FULL code including navbar: [pastebin/K4ngr4MN](http://pastebin.com/K4ngr4MN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have `position:fixed;` on your `a:active` declaration in your "code after navbar"

What that's doing is setting the x and y coordinate of the link to its exact offset, relative to the document when you click any link on the page. As such, the rest of the links, thinking that their position-fixed sibling is no longer in the relative flow, align to the left, taking up the now-empty space where the link used to live.

To remedy this, remove the `position:fixed;` style from the declaration.

`a:active {
        color: #1DFA3D;
        text-align: right;
        z-index: 9999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }`

Here's a fiddle of the after: http://jsfiddle.net/yo3L5qdy/